# SQL join type to have as many rows as each date for each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have these two tables

| date |
| --- |
| 2017-1 |
| 2017-2 |
| 2017-3 |
| 2017-4 |
| 2017-5 |
| 2017-6 |

and

| date | customer | no_orders | city_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-1 | 156 | 1 | DNZ |
| 2017-3 | 156 | 5 | LON |
| 2017-5 | 156 | 4 | DNZ |
| 2017-6 | 156 | 2 | YQB |

How can I join these two tables to have one row for each customer for all the dates same as below?

If on a date, the customer has no order, its `no_order` should be `0` and its `city_code` should be *the city_code of the previous date.*

| date | customer | no_orders | city_code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-1 | 156 | 1 | DNZ |
| 2017-2 | 156 | 0 | DNZ |
| 2017-3 | 156 | 5 | LON |
| 2017-4 | 156 | 0 | LON |
| 2017-5 | 156 | 4 | DNZ |
| 2017-6 | 156 | 2 | YQB |

This code by @Tim Biegeleisen resolved part 1 of my question but now I want to handle both parts with each other.

```
SELECT d.date, c.customer, COALESCE(t.no_orders, 0) AS no_orders
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM customers) c
LEFT JOIN customers t
    ON t.date = d.date AND
       t.customer = c.customer
ORDER BY c.customer, d.date;
```

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` your dates and customer table, and then `LEFT JOIN` to your second table.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the following calendar table approach:

```sql
SELECT d.date, c.customer, COALESCE(t.no_orders, 0) AS no_orders
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM customers) c
LEFT JOIN customers t
    ON t.date = d.date AND
       t.customer = c.customer
ORDER BY c.customer, d.date;
```

This assumes that the first table is called `dates` and the second table `customers`.  The query works by using a cross join to generate a set of all dates and customers.  We then left join to the second table to bring in the number of orders for a given customer on a given day.  Absent number of orders are reported as zero.